# Selecting values of record field from array of records - how to in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, select, plsql

Suppose we have the following type and variable definitions:

```
  type r_student_type is record(
    id    number,
    name  varchar2(32),
    class varchar2(32));

  type t_students_type is table of r_student_type;

  t_students t_students_type := t_students_type();
```

And later on the array `t_students` is filed with data, let's assume it will look like this:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| id   | name   | class |
+------+--------+-------+
| 4551 | Walter | A     |
+------+--------+-------+
| 4552 | Marie  | B     |
+------+--------+-------+
| 4553 | Hank   | B     |
+------+--------+-------+
| 4554 | Skyler | A     |
+------+--------+-------+
```

what I am looking for is a way to query a specific field-value of all records in the array `t_students`.
Say, for instance, we want to know if all students are in the same `class`.

I've tried something similar to:

```
select count(distinct class)
  into l_class_cnt
  from (select class
          from table(t_students));
```

but I'm getting the Error: `PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements`

I'm aware that I can use a `for-loop` to have access to all records in `t_students` and do whatever checking I want to, but I want to do the comparison in a single `SELECT` statement (and not sure if that even possible in Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the types in a package spec to use the variables in SQL:

```
create or replace package pkg as 
  type r_student_type is record(
    id    number,
    name  varchar2(32),
    class varchar2(32));

  type t_students_type is table of r_student_type;

  t_students t_students_type := t_students_type();
  l_class_cnt integer;
end;
/

declare
  t_students pkg.t_students_type := pkg.t_students_type();
  l_class_cnt integer;
begin
  select count(distinct class)
  into l_class_cnt
  from (select class
          from table(t_students));
          
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Found ' || l_class_cnt );
end;
/
Found 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RECORD` is a PL/SQL data type and cannot be used in an SQL scope, only a PL/SQL scope, and cannot be passed into a table collection expression if it is a locally-defined type.

You can change the type to an `OBJECT` and define it in the SQL scope (instead of a PL/SQL scope).

```sql
CREATE TYPE r_student_type IS OBJECT(
    id    number,
    name  varchar2(32),
    class varchar2(32)
);

CREATE TYPE t_students_type IS TABLE OF r_student_type;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(distinct class)
FROM   TABLE(
         t_students_type(
           r_student_type(1, 'Alice', 'Advanced'),
           r_student_type(2, 'Betty', 'Beginner'),
           r_student_type(3, 'Carol', 'Compiler Engineering')
         )
       );
```

and:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_class_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
  t_students t_students_type := t_students_type(
    r_student_type(1, 'Alice', 'Advanced'),
    r_student_type(2, 'Betty', 'Beginner'),
    r_student_type(3, 'Carol', 'Compiler Engineering')
  );
BEGIN
  SELECT count(distinct class)
  INTO   l_class_cnt
  FROM   table(t_students);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_class_cnt);
END;
/
```

Both work.

---

Alternatively, you can define the record and its collection type globally in a package (as per [Chris Saxon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76261166/1509264)), rather than as a locally defined type, and then you can only use the record and collection in a PL/SQL scope (but not in an SQL scope).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/elMIg_5s)